# what is a binary file and when to use writeBin() in R

Tags: r, binaryfiles

I am having trouble understanding the nature of binary format and its usefulness in R, so I experimented a little:

In R:

```
y1 = rbind(c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'd'))
write.table(y1, 'f1', quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
conn = file('f2', 'wb')
writeBin('a b\nc d\n', conn)
close(conn)
```

In bash:

```
cat f1
# a b
# c d
cat f2
# a b
# c d
```

These look exactly the same, but if I diff them:

```
diff f1 f2
# Binary files f1 and f2 differ
```

diff didn't tell me what the difference is though.

So back to the topic, what is a binary file (since everything is binary after all on a PC), and in what circumstances should I use it in R?

Comment: All files are "binary", it just depends on what interface you use to access the contents. readBin and writeBin are very low-level tools for when you need to write your own interface, or circumvent the ones you have.

Comment: type `hexdump -C f1` and `hexdump -C f2` and you'll see the difference (an extra `\0`, i.e. end of string, for `f2`)

Comment: @mdsumner Could you please give some examples of application of readBin and writeBin, or some references? Thanks.

Comment: help(readBin) is a good start

Answer (score 0):

Binary flies can use any of the 256 bit patterns. Ascii and other files are restricted. As such, binary files can obviously hold ascii text, as above, but are much more flexible.

[Useful from UMD](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/asciiBin.html)

And binary files' uses from the [docs](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html#Binary-files)

As for your `diff` command, it is standard behavior to output only that they are different and not give you any more information. I imagine that the line breaks are encoded differently.

Comment: Did you read the link I sent? I didn't include specific R examples because binary files are binary files.

Comment: Thanks. The link is helpful, but I think it's a bit outdated. Unicode files sure can use any of the 256 bit patterns?